# No shape named ... is known

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections, tikz-shape, tikz-path

For this error I can not find a correct answer

```
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %
    % Welcome to Overleaf --- just edit your LaTeX on the left,
    % and we'll compile it for you on the right. If you give
    % someone the link to this page, they can edit at the same
    % time. See the help menu above for more info. Enjoy!
    %
    % Note: you can export the pdf to see the result at full
    % resolution.

    %

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    %& -shell-escape

    % Create a Bode plot using Papanicola Robert's package bodegraph:

    % http://www.sciences-indus-cpge.apinc.org/Bode-Black-et-Nyquist-avec-Tikz

    % Author: Dazhi Jiang

    \documentclass[10pt]{article}

    %%%<

    \usepackage{verbatim}

    \usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}

    %\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

    \setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

    %%%>



    \begin{comment}

    :Title: Bode plot

    :Author: Dazhi Jiang

    :Tags: Bodegraph, PGF CVS, Signal Processing, Node positionning, 
    Plotting


    This tikz example display two bode plots.

    It requires the bodegraph_ package and GNUPLOT.


    .. _bodegraph: http://www.sciences-indus-cpge.apinc.org/Bode-Black-et-        Nyquist-avec-Tikz

    \end{comment}

    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{bodegraph}

    \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}


    \begin{document}

    % Define the layers to draw the diagram
    \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
    \pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
    \pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

    \begin{preview}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',
        ref lines/.style={thin, blue!60},
        ref points/.style={circle, black, opacity=0.7, fill, minimum size=         3pt, inner sep=0},
        every node/.style={font=\small},
        bode lines/.style={very thick, blue},
        Gclabel/.style={text=blue},
        xscale=12/3]

    \begin{scope}[yscale=4/110]
    \UnitedB
    \semilog{-1}{2}{-50}{60}

    % Bode plot (magnitude) for the original system, 4/(s/(1+2s)).
    % Asymptotic line
    \BodeAmp[ref lines, red!60]{-1:1.35}{\POAmpAsymp{4}{2.0}+\IntAmp{1}}
    % Bode plot
    \BodeAmp[bode lines, red, name path=Gomagnitude]{-1:1.35}{\POAmp{4}        {2.0}+\IntAmp{1}}

    % Bode plot (magnitude) for the compensated system, 4(1+s)/(s^2/(1+0.1s)).
    % Asymptotic line
    \BodeAmp[ref lines]{-1:2}{\APAmpAsymp{4}{0.1}{10}+2*\IntAmp{1}}
    % Bode plot
    \BodeAmp[bode lines, name path=magnitude]
        {-1:2}{\APAmp{4}{0.1}{10}+2*\IntAmp{1}}

    % Reference line, (0dB)
    \draw [name path=unitygain, ref lines] (-1,0) -- (2,0);

    % Crossover frequency of the original system
    \path [name intersections={of=magnitude and unitygain, by={a,b}}]
    (a) circle (2pt)
    (b) circle (2pt);
    \node (coref) [ref points, label={[blue]below left:$\omega_c$}] 
        at (a,b) {};

    % Crossover frequency of the compensated system
    \path [name intersections={of=Gomagnitude and unitygain, by=Gocrossover}];
    \node (Gocoref) [ref points, label={[red]below:$\omega_{co}$}] 
        at (Gocrossover) {};

    % Labels for the original system (open-loop)
    \node [Gclabel, text=red] at (-0.7, 15) {$-20$dB/dec};
    \node [Gclabel, text=red] at (0.5, -30) {$-40$dB/dec};
    \node (KG) [Gclabel, red!60, text=red, draw] 
        at (-0.5, -30) {$KG(s)=\dfrac{4}{s(1+2s)}$};
    \draw (KG.east) edge [->, shorten >=1pt, thick, red, bend right=1.5] 
        (0.4, -10);

    % Labels for the compensated system (open-loop)
    \node [ref points, label={[blue]below left:$\omega_2$}] at (0, 0) {};
    \node [ref points, label={[blue]below right:$\omega_3$}] at (1, 0) {};
    \node [Gclabel] at (-0.4, 40) {$-40$dB/dec};
    \node [Gclabel] at (0.5, 10) {$-20$dB/dec};
    \node [Gclabel] at (1.6, -20) {$-40$dB/dec};
    \node (KDG) [Gclabel, blue!60, text=blue, draw] 
        at (1.4, 40) {$KD(s)G(s)=\dfrac{4(1+s)}{s^2(1+0.1s)}$};
    \draw (KDG.west) edge [->, shorten >=1pt, thick, blue, bend right=1.5] 
        (0.17, 10);

    % Axes label
    \node [below=6pt] at (0.5,-50) {Frequency, $\omega$};
    \node [rotate=90] at (-1.25,5) {Magnitude, $20\log(|G(\text{j}        \omega)|)$};


    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[yshift=-3.5cm,yscale=4/180]
    \UniteDegre
    \OrdBode{30}
    \semilog{-1}{2}{-180}{0}

    %         Bode plot (phase) for the original system, 4/(s/(1+2s)).
    % Asymptotic line
    \BodeArg[ref lines, red!60]{-1:2}{\POArgAsymp{4}{2.0}+\IntArg{1}}
    %Bode plot
    \BodeArg[bode lines, red, name path=Gophase]{-1:2}{\POArg{4}        {2}+\IntArg{1}}

    % Bode plot (magnitude) for the compensated system, 4(1+s)/(s^2        /(1+0.1s)).
    % Asymptotic line
    \BodeArg[ref lines]{-1:2}{\APArgAsymp{4}{0.1}{10}+2*\IntArg{1}}
    % Bode plot
    \BodeArg[bode lines, name path=phase]{-1:2}{\APArg{4}{0.1}{10}+2*        \IntArg{1}}

    % Phase margin of the original system
    \path [name path=Gowcref] (Gocrossover) -- ++(0,-330);
    \path [name intersections={of=Gophase and Gowcref, by=Gophasemargin}];
    \node (Gopmref) [ref points] at (Gophasemargin) {};
    \draw [ref lines, red!60, densely dotted] (Gocoref.south) --                 (Gopmref.north);
    \draw [ref lines, <->, red] let \p1=(Gophasemargin)
        in
            (Gopmref.south) -- node[left, Gclabel, text=red]                 {$\text{PM}_o$} (\x1,-180);

    % Phase margin of the compensated system
    \path[name path=wcref] (crossover) -- ++(0,-300);
    \path [name intersections={of=phase and wcref, by=phasemargin}];
    \node (pmref) [ref points] at (phasemargin) {};
    \draw [ref lines, densely dotted] (coref.south) -- (pmref.north);
    \draw [ref lines, <->, blue] let \p1=(phasemargin)
        in
            (pmref.south) -- node[left, Gclabel] {PM} (\x1,-180);

    % System Labels
    \node (KGphase) [Gclabel, red!60, text=red, draw] 
        at (-0.5, -40) {$KG(s)=\dfrac{4}{s(1+2s)}$};
    \draw[->, shorten >=1pt, thick, red] 
        (KGphase.south) .. controls +(down:30) and +(0.1,10) .. (-0.65,         -114);

    \node (KDGphase) [Gclabel, blue!60, text=blue, draw]
        at (1.4, -40) {$KD(s)G(s)=\dfrac{4(1+s)}{s^2(1+0.1s)}$};
    \draw[->, shorten >=1pt, thick, blue] 
        (KDGphase.south) .. controls +(down:40) and +(0.1,30) .. (1.1,         -146);

    % Axes label
    \node [below=6pt] at (0.5, -180) {Frequency, $\omega$};
    \node [rotate=90] at (-1.25, -90) {Phase, $\angle G(\text{j}\omega)$};
    \end{scope}

    % Background
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \path (-1.4cm,2.8cm) node (tl) {};
        \path (2.3cm, -8.4cm) node (br) {};

        \path[fill=brown!20] (tl) rectangle (br);
    \end{pgfonlayer}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{preview}
    \end{document}
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

It is in texample.net

0
down vote
accept

Two things: I made a mistake in the code. The correct is

% Crossover frequency of the original system

`\path [name intersections={of=magnitude and unitygain, by=crossover}];
\node (coref) [ref points, label={[blue]below left:$\omega_c$}] 
    at (crossover) {};`

From what I see in the code the syntax is correct. I still get the error when compiling what you published. It seems that the error appears when compiling. WHAT IS THE PROBLEM? I do not understand!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The problem is that Ti*k*Z does not find two intersections in `\path [name intersections={of=magnitude and unitygain, by={a,b}}]
    (a) circle (2pt)
    (b) circle (2pt);`. Most likely this means that there are not two intersections. Can you please give us a hint what the paths `magnitude` and `unitygain` are, and check whether they intersect twice.

Answer (score 4):

I think I have fixed it. `unitygain` is just a horizontal line and intersects only once with `magnitude`. Further, the command `\node (coref) [ref points, label={[blue]below left:$\omega_c$}] at (a,b) {};` would not work if there were really two intersections, so I fixed that as well.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Welcome to Overleaf --- just edit your LaTeX on the left,
% and we'll compile it for you on the right. If you give
% someone the link to this page, they can edit at the same
% time. See the help menu above for more info. Enjoy!
%
% Note: you can export the pdf to see the result at full
% resolution.

%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%& -shell-escape

% Create a Bode plot using Papanicola Robert's package bodegraph:

% http://www.sciences-indus-cpge.apinc.org/Bode-Black-et-Nyquist-avec-Tikz

% Author: Dazhi Jiang

\documentclass[10pt]{article}

%%%<

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}

%\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

%%%>



\begin{comment}

:Title: Bode plot

:Author: Dazhi Jiang

:Tags: Bodegraph, PGF CVS, Signal Processing, Node positionning, 
Plotting


This tikz example display two bode plots.

It requires the bodegraph_ package and GNUPLOT.


.. _bodegraph: http://www.sciences-indus-cpge.apinc.org/Bode-Black-et-        Nyquist-avec-Tikz

\end{comment}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bodegraph}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}

% Define the layers to draw the diagram
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',
    ref lines/.style={thin, blue!60},
    ref points/.style={circle, black, opacity=0.7, fill, minimum size=         3pt, inner sep=0},
    every node/.style={font=\small},
    bode lines/.style={very thick, blue},
    Gclabel/.style={text=blue},
    xscale=12/3]

\begin{scope}[yscale=4/110]
\UnitedB
\semilog{-1}{2}{-50}{60}

% Bode plot (magnitude) for the original system, 4/(s/(1+2s)).
% Asymptotic line
\BodeAmp[ref lines, red!60]{-1:1.35}{\POAmpAsymp{4}{2.0}+\IntAmp{1}}
% Bode plot
\BodeAmp[bode lines, red, name path=Gomagnitude]{-1:1.35}{\POAmp{4}        {2.0}+\IntAmp{1}}

% Bode plot (magnitude) for the compensated system, 4(1+s)/(s^2/(1+0.1s)).
% Asymptotic line
\BodeAmp[ref lines]{-1:2}{\APAmpAsymp{4}{0.1}{10}+2*\IntAmp{1}}
% Bode plot
\BodeAmp[bode lines, name path=magnitude]
    {-1:2}{\APAmp{4}{0.1}{10}+2*\IntAmp{1}}

% Reference line, (0dB)
\draw [name path=unitygain, ref lines] (-1,0) -- (2,0);

% Crossover frequency of the original system
\path [name intersections={of=magnitude and unitygain, by={a}}]
(a) ;
\node (coref) [ref points, label={[blue]below left:$\omega_c$}] 
    at (a) {};

% Crossover frequency of the compensated system
\path [name intersections={of=Gomagnitude and unitygain, by=Gocrossover}];
\node (Gocoref) [ref points, label={[red]below:$\omega_{co}$}] 
    at (Gocrossover) {};

% Labels for the original system (open-loop)
\node [Gclabel, text=red] at (-0.7, 15) {$-20$dB/dec};
\node [Gclabel, text=red] at (0.5, -30) {$-40$dB/dec};
\node (KG) [Gclabel, red!60, text=red, draw] 
    at (-0.5, -30) {$KG(s)=\dfrac{4}{s(1+2s)}$};
\draw (KG.east) edge [->, shorten >=1pt, thick, red, bend right=1.5] 
    (0.4, -10);

% Labels for the compensated system (open-loop)
\node [ref points, label={[blue]below left:$\omega_2$}] at (0, 0) {};
\node [ref points, label={[blue]below right:$\omega_3$}] at (1, 0) {};
\node [Gclabel] at (-0.4, 40) {$-40$dB/dec};
\node [Gclabel] at (0.5, 10) {$-20$dB/dec};
\node [Gclabel] at (1.6, -20) {$-40$dB/dec};
\node (KDG) [Gclabel, blue!60, text=blue, draw] 
    at (1.4, 40) {$KD(s)G(s)=\dfrac{4(1+s)}{s^2(1+0.1s)}$};
\draw (KDG.west) edge [->, shorten >=1pt, thick, blue, bend right=1.5] 
    (0.17, 10);

% Axes label
\node [below=6pt] at (0.5,-50) {Frequency, $\omega$};
\node [rotate=90] at (-1.25,5) {Magnitude, $20\log(|G(\text{j}        \omega)|)$};


\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-3.5cm,yscale=4/180]
\UniteDegre
\OrdBode{30}
\semilog{-1}{2}{-180}{0}

%         Bode plot (phase) for the original system, 4/(s/(1+2s)).
% Asymptotic line
\BodeArg[ref lines, red!60]{-1:2}{\POArgAsymp{4}{2.0}+\IntArg{1}}
%Bode plot
\BodeArg[bode lines, red, name path=Gophase]{-1:2}{\POArg{4}        {2}+\IntArg{1}}

% Bode plot (magnitude) for the compensated system, 4(1+s)/(s^2        /(1+0.1s)).
% Asymptotic line
\BodeArg[ref lines]{-1:2}{\APArgAsymp{4}{0.1}{10}+2*\IntArg{1}}
% Bode plot
\BodeArg[bode lines, name path=phase]{-1:2}{\APArg{4}{0.1}{10}+2*        \IntArg{1}}

% Phase margin of the original system
\path [name path=Gowcref] (Gocrossover) -- ++(0,-330);
\path [name intersections={of=Gophase and Gowcref, by=Gophasemargin}];
\node (Gopmref) [ref points] at (Gophasemargin) {};
\draw [ref lines, red!60, densely dotted] (Gocoref.south) --                 (Gopmref.north);
\draw [ref lines, <->, red] let \p1=(Gophasemargin)
    in
        (Gopmref.south) -- node[left, Gclabel, text=red]                 {$\text{PM}_o$} (\x1,-180);

% Phase margin of the compensated system
\path[name path=wcref] (Gocrossover) -- ++(0,-300);
\path [name intersections={of=phase and wcref, by=phasemargin}];
\node (pmref) [ref points] at (phasemargin) {};
\draw [ref lines, densely dotted] (coref.south) -- (pmref.north);
\draw [ref lines, <->, blue] let \p1=(phasemargin)
    in
        (pmref.south) -- node[left, Gclabel] {PM} (\x1,-180);

% System Labels
\node (KGphase) [Gclabel, red!60, text=red, draw] 
    at (-0.5, -40) {$KG(s)=\dfrac{4}{s(1+2s)}$};
\draw[->, shorten >=1pt, thick, red] 
    (KGphase.south) .. controls +(down:30) and +(0.1,10) .. (-0.65,         -114);

\node (KDGphase) [Gclabel, blue!60, text=blue, draw]
    at (1.4, -40) {$KD(s)G(s)=\dfrac{4(1+s)}{s^2(1+0.1s)}$};
\draw[->, shorten >=1pt, thick, blue] 
    (KDGphase.south) .. controls +(down:40) and +(0.1,30) .. (1.1,         -146);

% Axes label
\node [below=6pt] at (0.5, -180) {Frequency, $\omega$};
\node [rotate=90] at (-1.25, -90) {Phase, $\angle G(\text{j}\omega)$};
\end{scope}

% Background
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \path (-1.4cm,2.8cm) node (tl) {};
    \path (2.3cm, -8.4cm) node (br) {};

    \path[fill=brown!20] (tl) rectangle (br);
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice the output.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks, but the code seems to essentially from [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/bode-plot/) except for the `\path [name intersections={of=magnitude and unitygain, by={a,b}}]
    (a) circle (2pt)
    (b) circle (2pt);
    \node (coref) [ref points, label={[blue]below left:$\omega_c$}] 
        at (a,b) {};` piece which caused the problems.